# videojs not working in ie8 with amazon s3 signed URL

Tags: video.js

Ok,

Im having trouble with the fallback to flash in IE8.

Can anyone see a porblem with the following URL as im thinking this is something to do with it being an Amazon S3 signed URL.

https://download300kbps.s3.amazonaws.com/abadie_020211_webcast_300kbps.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFBCGFZJE5IHBQFA&Expires=1376585074&Signature=TBTookVUnmXwgn2GaED%2Ftv0FDfY%3D

It runs fine in IE10 but as soon as I switch the browse mode to IE8 I get the following error and im all out of ideas:

Video Error,[object Object] 
Flash Error,srcnotfound,example_video_1_flash_api

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Neil

Answer (score 1):

Something to try would be to form the URL to the object using the bucket name as part of the path, instead of a prefix to the domain.  So something like this:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/download300kbps/abadie_020211_webcast_300kbps.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFBCGFZJE5IHBQFA&Expires=1376585074&Signature=TBTookVUnmXwgn2GaED%2Ftv0FDfY%3D

There are some funny quirks with both ways of representing an Amazon S3 object via a URL.

You may also want to check to make sure the content type of the object is set correctly, thought it most likely is not the cause.

Good luck!